# Wine won't install

Tags: 10.10, wine

I just reinstalled 10 - 10 on an old Dell desktop w/ 3G of ram, two hard drives, one with XP Pro and the other with 10-10.  A Windows virus took out one drive and fouled my boot loader.

I had Wine installed  and it worked well.  After the reinstall with a new CD, Wine will not install.  I tied Synaptic Package manager,  I tried to download and install from the Wine Web site and I tried the command line.

Every time I get 3/4 of the way through I get through the install I get ask to put the CD in the drive.  The manager looks for a file
"pool/main/a/ auto

The file (a) does not exist on the CD. The install hangs.
My question is Where can I get an iso with this file on it?

Comment: My guess would be corrupted data or damaged medium, possible problem could also be a dirty medium or dust in DVD unit.

Comment: did you use a live cd to install?

Answer (score 1):

try `touch /forcefsck` or go to update manager then to source and remove your cd so it wont try to install wine form the cd and just from internet